# Back to Previous Window

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

i'm new in `Python` and `PyQt4`.
I want to ask `"How to back to previous Window ?"`
i have 2 file in here, file 'login' and 'signup'

`here file login.py`

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QLabel, \
                        QApplication, QGridLayout

from signup import SignUp


class Login(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Login, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Login")

        self.login_window()

    def login_window(self):
        self.login_layout = QGridLayout()

        self.login_button = QPushButton("Login")
        self.signup_button = QPushButton("Sign Up")

        self.login_layout.addWidget(self.login_button, 2, 0)
        self.login_layout.addWidget(self.signup_button, 2, 1)

        self.signup_button.clicked.connect(self.signup_show)

        self.setLayout(self.login_layout)
        self.show()

    def signup_show(self):
        self.signupshow = SignUp()
        self.hide()
        self.signupshow.show()

    def check_signup(self):
        SignUp.check_signup()
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    login = Login()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`and here is signup.py`

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QLabel, \
                        QApplication, QGridLayout


class SignUp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SignUp, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Sign Up")

        self.signup_window()

    def signup_window(self):

        self.signup_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.signup_button = QPushButton("Sign Up")
        self.signup_layout.addWidget(self.signup_button, 2, 0, 1, 0)
        self.signup_button.clicked.connect(self.check_signup)
        self.setLayout(self.signup_layout)
        self.show()

    def check_signup(self):
        self.close()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    signup = SignUp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

my problem is, when i push button `signup` from signup.py, it's close but window Login is not show.
i think i don't have any `trigger` in signup.py for `check_signup` in login.py
in this code, i delete some `Line Edit` and `Label`. I think it's not a problem.
i hope someone will help, Thank you before :)
and if you answer this questtion, i hope you will explain a little bit of the logic, thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve (your description is kind of confusing), but let's start here. I put all your code in **one** file, since you need to `import` each other (which leads to cyclic import). Then, I just added these two lines

```
self.login = Login()
self.login.show()
```

into `check_signup` method of `SignUp` class, which pops-up `Login` window. If this is not your desired result, please let us know and provide us a better description. The code follows:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QLabel, \
                        QApplication, QGridLayout

class Login(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Login, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Login")

        self.login_window()

    def login_window(self):
        self.login_layout = QGridLayout()

        self.login_button = QPushButton("Login")
        self.signup_button = QPushButton("Sign Up")

        self.login_layout.addWidget(self.login_button, 2, 0)
        self.login_layout.addWidget(self.signup_button, 2, 1)

        self.signup_button.clicked.connect(self.signup_show)

        self.setLayout(self.login_layout)
        self.show()

    def signup_show(self):
        self.signupshow = SignUp()
        self.hide()
        self.signupshow.show()

    def check_signup(self):
        SignUp.check_signup()
        self.show()


class SignUp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SignUp, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Sign Up")

        self.signup_window()

    def signup_window(self):

        self.signup_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.signup_button = QPushButton("Sign Up")
        self.signup_layout.addWidget(self.signup_button, 2, 0, 1, 0)
        self.signup_button.clicked.connect(self.check_signup)
        self.setLayout(self.signup_layout)
        self.show()

    def check_signup(self):
        self.login = Login()
        self.login.show()
        self.close()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    signup = SignUp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: hi sir, thanks for your answer.   
i already try before i split the Class become 2 file hehehehe  
what i want is from 2 different file :)  
sorry for my bad english -_-

Comment: May I know why do you need two files? :)

Comment: forget about that, i'm realy confused with 2 file.
and i now back to 1 file hahahaha. thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use signal-slot connections:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class WidgetA(QtGui.QWidget):
    open_b = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WidgetA, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(100, 100)
        self.l = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.close_btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Close')
        self.b_btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Open B')
        self.b_btn.clicked.connect(self.b_btn_clicked)
        self.l.addWidget(self.close_btn)
        self.l.addWidget(self.b_btn)
        self.setLayout(self.l)

    def b_btn_clicked(self):
        self.open_b.emit()
        self.hide()


class WidgetB(QtGui.QWidget):
    open_a = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WidgetB, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(100, 100)
        self.l = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.close_btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Close')
        self.close_btn.clicked.connect(self.hide)
        self.a_btn = QtGui.QPushButton('Open A')
        self.a_btn.clicked.connect(self.a_btn_clicked)
        self.l.addWidget(self.close_btn)
        self.l.addWidget(self.a_btn)
        self.setLayout(self.l)

    def a_btn_clicked(self):
        self.open_a.emit()
        self.hide()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    a = WidgetA()
    b = WidgetB()
    a.open_b.connect(lambda: b.show())
    b.open_a.connect(lambda: a.show())
    a.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: hmmmm that's work.  
what i need is create variable signal for each class and call the variable in fun main ?
What is the `emit` function?
and why have to using `lambda`, i delete the lamda and i got error hahahaha
thank you sir for explain :)

Comment: `emit()` "sends" signal to all "slots" which are listening to it. Lambdas are these slots, which also may be normal functions (like `a_btn_clicked` and `b_btn_clicked`). Here's official explanation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Comment: Here's pyqt-specific docs: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html